# How to set the "TO" field dynamically in Vcalendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set the email address of the log on user in "To" field while exporting to Vcalendar.

```
public static void ExportToIcalender(HttpContext ctx, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string organizer, string location, string summary, string description)
{
    string DateFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
    ctx.Response.ClearContent();
    ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
    ctx.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=appointment.ics");

    ctx.Response.Write("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nVERSION:2.0");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nMETHOD:PUBLISH");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nBEGIN:VEVENT");
    **ctx.Response.Write("\nORGANIZER:MAILTO:" + organizer);**

    ctx.Response.Write("\nDTSTART:" + startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    ctx.Response.Write("\nDTEND:" + endDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    ctx.Response.Write("\nLOCATION:" + location);
    ctx.Response.Write("\nUID:" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat) + "@mysite.com");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nDTSTAMP:" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    ctx.Response.Write("\nSUMMARY:" + summary);
    description = HtmlRemoval.StripTagsRegexCompiled(description).Replace("\r\n", "\\n");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nDESCRIPTION:" + description);
    ctx.Response.Write("\nPRIORITY:5");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nCLASS:PUBLIC");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nEND:VEVENT");
    ctx.Response.Write("\nEND:VCALENDAR");
    ctx.Response.End();
}
```

This line does not help me:

```
ctx.Response.Write("\nORGANIZER:MAILTO:" + organizer)
```

Kindly provide soln.

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting the attendee property

```
ctx.Response.Write("\nATTENDEE;CN=someone@email.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:someone@email.com");
```

Comment: Should I use ATTENDEE instead of ORGANIZER ?

Comment: If you want to set the yes field, then yes. Try creating an appointment in outlook, saving it and opening in notepad and see for yourself.